# How to select text in Xpath?

Tags: select, xpath, text

I want to select some detail from a webpage content

```
<div id="realty_widget_property_description" class="property_block realty_widget_property_description widget widget-2 alt">
<p class="title "><strong>Apartment for Rent </strong></p>
<div class="property-description ">
        <p class="property_description">
        </p><p>– Property ID: P-000324<br>
– Location: Phsar Chas<br>
– Price: $350/month<br>
– Bed/Bath: 2 beds / 2 Baths<br>
– Size: 4m x 18m<br>
– Story: 1st<br>
– Fully Furnished<br>
– Description: This apartment is in residential area and good location for living with comfortable and fresh air. There are 2 bedrooms, 2 bathrooms, a living room, a kitchen and the balcony. Close to everywhere in town such as school, market, clinic, Bank, coffee shop and just ride a few minutes to Phsar Chas Market.<br>
```

How can I select Property ID, Location, price,size, story and description if they all stay in the same class?

Comment: Which version of XPath do you use, which data exactly do you want? There are text nodes in that last `p` element you show, you can select them with e.g. `//div[@id = 'realty_widget_property_description']/div[@class = 'property-description ']/p[2]/text()`, that would give you e.g. `– Property ID: P-000324`, `
– Location: Phsar Chas` and so on.

Comment: I want to select it one by one not select all

Comment: Then add a positional predicate e.g. `//div[@id = 'realty_widget_property_description']/div[@class = 'property-description ']/p[2]/text()[1]` gives you a text node with the string value `– Property ID: P-000324`.

Comment: I want only P-00324. Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use e.g. `substring-after(//div[@id = 'realty_widget_property_description']/div[@class = 'property-description ']/p[2]/text()[1], ': ')` to extract a string value. But be aware that that XPath expression returns a string value and not a node, so you need to make sure you use an XPath API that supports that.

Comment: Mr.Martin Honnen Can u please help me? my code is not working echo $xpath->evaluate('//div[contains(@id,"realty_widget_property_description")]/div[contains(@class,"property-description")]/p[2]/text()[1]')->item(0)->nodeValue; I want only P-00324

Comment: Well which programming language is that and which XPath API do you use? If that is XPath with PHP, then I think doing `$xpath->evaluate("substring-after(//div[@id = 'realty_widget_property_description']/div[@class = 'property-description ']/p[2]/text()[1], ': ')")` would return a string with the wanted result.

Comment: Hello  Martin Honnen;What if I want to select data after Property ID: that in the different class? Can I use regex in xpath just like "/Property ID:(.*)/". I want all the data that after Property ID: though it is in different class. Please help me. Thank u very much